# C++/STL string: How to mimic regex like function with wildcards?

Tags: c++, string, stl, wildcard

I would like to compare 4 character string using wildcards.

For example:

```
std::string wildcards[]=
{"H?  ", "RH? ", "H[0-5]  "};
/*in the last one I need to check if string is "H0  ",..., and "H5  " */
```

Is it possible to manage to realize only by STL?

Thanks,
Arman.

***EDIT:***

Can we do it without boost.regex?

Or should I add yet another library dependences to my project?:)

Comment: Did you mean `std::string wildcards[] = { ...`?

Comment: What do you mean by "using only the STL"? If all you want to do is handle basic globbing, you should be just fine with something simple based on a `for` loop....

Comment: The answer to "is it possible to do Y in language X" is usually yes where X is not a language feature.  Even then you can usually find a work around.  So yes, probably.  When it comes to making suggestions as to how to do it, I think we're going to need a clearer and more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: @David: Thanks for noticing it:)(corrected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: What about  Boost.Xpressive?(I have no idea what is it,but googling pop it up).

Comment: @Arman: I would go with Boost.Regex, since the C++0x draft regex is based on it

Comment: @Stephan: Is that means that in the nearfuture I will be able to change boost::regex to std::tr1::regex or something like that?

Comment: @Arman: str::tr1::regex is alread part of gcc and MSVC 2008 as a feature pack. In the future, it will be just `include <regex>` if IIRC.

Comment: @Stephan: Unfortunately feature pack does not support MSVC2008 Express.

Comment: @Arman: uh, didn't know about that "feature" :-(. Then use Boost and wait (MSVC 2010 moves TR1 into the std namespace).

Comment: @Stephan: Well MS keeps nice things inside the commercial products.
BTW, I just discovered that MSVC2010 Betta Express includes PPL and TR1 headers.

Answer (score 2):

No - you need boost::regex

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions were made for this sort of thing.  I can understand your reluctance to avoid a dependency, but in this case it's probably justified.

You might check your C++ compiler to see if it includes any built-in regular expression library.  For example, Microsoft includes [CAtlRegExp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3zs4axe(VS.80).aspx).

Barring that, your problem doesn't look too difficult to write custom code for.

Comment: @Mark:Thank you for answer. Actually the code is platform independent. currently it is using several strcmps but that way is nonextensible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without introducing a new library dependency, but to do so you'd end up writing a regular expression engine yourself (or at least a subset of one).

Is there some reason you don't want to use a library for this?

Comment: @Joe: Yes, you are right, seems to me I need to include Boost.Regex here. The code is pure C++/STL, and it is portable. Sometimes on different machines there is no BOOST installed.

Comment: If you need compilability on machines without boost, you could extract the boost regex headers and source and integrate them directly into your project. I think I remember seeing discussion of doing that on the boost users mailing list at some point.

Comment: Yes, thats true, this is the bcp tool.