# C++ - Splitting Filename and File Extension

Tags: c++, windows, string, split

Ok, first of all I don't want to use Boost, or any external libraries. I just want to use the **C++ Standard Library**. I can easily split strings with a given delimiter with my `split()` function:

```
void split(std::string &string, std::vector<std::string> &tokens, const char &delim) {
    std::string ea;
    std::stringstream stream(string);
    while(getline(stream, ea, delim))
        tokens.push_back(ea);
}
```

I do this on filenames. But there's a problem. There are files that have extensions like: `tar.gz`, `tar.bz2`, etc. Also there are some filenames that have extra dots. `Some.file.name.tar.gz`. I wish to separate `Some.file.name` and `tar.gz` **Note:** The number of dots in a filename isn't constant.

I also tried `PathFindExtension` but no luck. Is this possible? If so, please enlighten me. Thank you.

Edit: I'm very sorry about not specifying the OS. It's Windows.

Comment: You want to use only the C++ Standard Library, so you try the OS-specific function `PathFindExtension`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could use `std::string` [`find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) to get the index of the last `.`, and [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to cut the string (although the "complex extensions" involving multiple dots will require additional work).

Comment: This method will fail when encountering files with paths like such: **C:\Some.Folder\somefile**

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy, you can do `find_last_of("/\\.")` and check that it is a `.` to protect against your example.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way of doing what you want that does not involve a database of extensions for your purpose. There's nothing magical about extensions, they are just part of a filename (if you `gunzip foo.tar.gz` you'll likely get a foo.tar, so for this application .gz actually is "the extension"). So, in order to do what you want, build a database of extensions that you want to look for and fall back on "last dot" if you don't find one.

Comment: +1 for the phrase "for your purpose". General file name splitting is near impossible; and not very useful. (If the application must be portable, then the "last dot" heuristic should be extended to handle Unix hidden files, which have names starting with a dot.)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the C++ standard library -- that is, it's not in the Standard --, but every operating system I know of provides this functionality in a variety of ways.

In Windows you can use _splitpath(), and in Linux you can use dirname() & basename()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed filenames like `*.tar.gz`, which can not be split consistently, due to the fact that (at least in Windows) the `.tar` part isn't part of the extension. You'll either have to keep a list for these special cases and use a one-dot `string::rfind` for the rest or find some pre-implemented way. Note that the `.tar.*` extensions aren't infinite, and very much standardized (there's about ten of them I think).

Comment: But the tar utility does use tar.gz, tar.bz2, tar.7z, tar.z, etc consistently as far as I see it. Tar even auto-detects the compression algorithm you want when creating a file with such an extension. Your examples aren't what I (and the OP) was talking about (the `tar.*` files)

Comment: GNU tar does; not all versions do. Nor do other GNU apps, or POSIX apps. That should make it clear why such knowledge can't be in the C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a look-up table of file extensions that you think you might encounter. And also add a command line option to add a new one to the look-up table if you encounter anything new. Then parse through the file name to see if it any entry in the look-up table is a sub-string in the file name.

EDIT: You can also refer to this question: [C++/STL string: How to mimic regex like function with wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471651/c-stl-string-how-to-mimic-regex-like-function-with-wildcards)